# Describe EC2 instances Filter instance name using AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to use CLI commands to filter those instances which have particular tags and store it in a file on my local everytime I run the Jenkins job.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Hello,Values=exclude"  --output table --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Id.InstanceId, State:State.name,Contact:tag:OwnerContact, InstanceProfileName:InstanceProfileName} > Book.txt
```

I get the output in text file successfully, however for two of my parameters InstanceProfileName and OwnerContact , I get the output as None.

I tried a variety of combinations, still not able to output the instance name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that can output various parameters, including tag values:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Id:InstanceId,State:State.Name,Profile:IamInstanceProfile.Arn,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value}"
```

To get the syntax right, just try one element at a time. Start with:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*]"
```

then add parameters, eg:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].Tags"
```

Then try each value that you want. Finally, string it all together in a big command.

To understand the `--query` options, take a look at: [JMESPath Tutorial](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: Cheers , Works fine John !!  Just one more question, In the above scenario , when I output it to a file as table form, I am getting all the values such as instance Id, state name and all in one table. However, getting Tags in another table below rather than another column in the same table. Anything different that needs to be done ?

Comment: Tags are a 1-to-many output, so it's not easy to output in any format except JSON (which supports sub-objects). You might want to run two queries -- one for tags and one for the rest.

Comment: Hi @Sriram, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Will check it out regarding Tags as to what would be the better choice, thanks for the soln!  Appreciate it .